# Counting bigrams from user input in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm stuck and need a little guidance. I'm trying hard to learn Python on my own using Grok Learning. Below is the Problem and example output along with where I am in the code. I appreciate any tips that will help me solve this problem.

> *In linguistics, a bigram is a pair of adjacent words in a sentence. The sentence "**The big red ball.**" has three bigrams: The big, big
>   red, and red ball.*
>
> *Write a program to read in multiple lines of input from the user, where each line is a space-separated sentence of words. Your program
>   should then count up how many times each of the bigrams occur across
>   all input sentences. The bigrams should be treated in a case
>   insensitive manner by converting the input lines to lowercase. Once
>   the user stops entering input, your program should print out each of
>   the bigrams that appear more than once, along with their corresponding
>   frequencies. For example:*
>
> ```
> Line: The big red ball
> Line: The big red ball is near the big red box
> Line: I am near the box
> Line: 
> near the: 2
> red ball: 2
> the big: 3
> big red: 3
> ```

I haven't gotten very far with my code and am really stuck.  But here is where I am:

```
words = set()
line = input("Line: ")
while line != '':
  words.add(line)
  line = input("Line: ")
```

Am I even doing this right? Try not to import any modules and just use built-in functionality.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Hi @Jeff, when approaching problems like this think about them with out the actual code. Try to describe them in english. Step 1 read line of input. Step 2 break lines into bigrams, step 3 count bigrams.
Until you have an outline of what you need to do. It is difficult to code. 

Your first set of code almost completes step 1 reading input. see inspectorG4dget answer. for step 1.

Comment: OK I am officially further than I have been in days. Progress is progress :) Thank-you!!

Answer (score 6):

Let's start with the function that receives a sentence (with punctuation) and returns a list of all lowercase bigrams found.

So, we first need to strip all non-alphanumerics from the sentence, convert all letters to lowercase counterparts, and then split the sentence by spaces into a list of words:

```
import re

def bigrams(sentence):
    text = re.sub('\W', ' ', sentence.lower())
    words = text.split()
    return zip(words, words[1:])
```

We'll use the standard (builtin) [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) package for regular expression based substitution of non-alphanumerics with spaces, and the builtin `zip` function to pair-up consecutive words. (We pair the list of words with the same list, but shifted by one element.)

Now we can test it:

```
>>> bigrams("The big red ball")
[('the', 'big'), ('big', 'red'), ('red', 'ball')]
>>> bigrams("THE big, red, ball.")
[('the', 'big'), ('big', 'red'), ('red', 'ball')]
>>> bigrams(" THE  big,red,ball!!?")
[('the', 'big'), ('big', 'red'), ('red', 'ball')]
```

Next, for counting bigrams found in each sentence, you might use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

For example, like this:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
for line in ["The big red ball", "The big red ball is near the big red box", "I am near the box"]:
    counts.update(bigrams(line))
```

We get:

```
>>> Counter({('the', 'big'): 3, ('big', 'red'): 3, ('red', 'ball'): 2, ('near', 'the'): 2, ('red', 'box'): 1, ('i', 'am'): 1, ('the', 'box'): 1, ('ball', 'is'): 1, ('am', 'near'): 1, ('is', 'near'): 1})
```

Now we just need to print those that appear more than once:

```
for bigr, cnt in counts.items():
    if cnt > 1:
        print("{0[0]} {0[1]}: {1}".format(bigr, cnt))
```

All put together, with a loop for user input, instead of the fixed list:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def bigrams(sentence):
    text = re.sub('\W', ' ', sentence.lower())
    words = text.split()
    return zip(words, words[1:])

counts = Counter()
while True:
    line = input("Line: ")
    if not line:
        break
    counts.update(bigrams(line))

for bigr, cnt in counts.items():
    if cnt > 1:
        print("{0[0]} {0[1]}: {1}".format(bigr, cnt))
```

The output:

```
Line: The big red ball
Line: The big red ball is near the big red box
Line: I am near the box
Line: 
near the: 2
red ball: 2
big red: 3
the big: 3
```

Comment: Would +1 again for the maximum usage of the batteries included.

Comment: The only problem with this is that Grok Learning does not like importing modules like re. They want me to learn by using built-in functionality. Thank-you for this though, I will take from it what I can.

Comment: @JeffSingleton, `re` is needed only to strip punctuation, so you can skip that part if it's not required (although I wanted to show in my answer that preprocessing is also important). `Counter` can also be simply (re-)implemented -- but the beauty of Python is actually in having all those nice pieces ready at your disposal. That's why the motto of Python is "with batteries included."

Answer (score 2):

```
words = []
while True:
    line = input("Line: ").strip().lower()
    if not line: break
    words.extend(line.split())


counts = {}
for t in zip(words[::2], words[1::2]):
    if t not in counts: counts[t] = 0
    counts[t] += 1
```

Comment: Thank-you @inspectorG4dget.  I asked for guidance and that is what you gave. I'm still working toward a solution, but this helped me get passed where I was.

Answer (score 0):

```
usr_input = "Here is a sentence without multiple bigrams. Without multiple bigrams, we cannot test a sentence."

def get_bigrams(word_string):
    words = [word.lower().strip(',.') for word in word_string.split(" ")]
    pairs = ["{} {}".format(w, words[i+1]) for i, w in enumerate(words) if i < len(words) - 1]
    bigrams = {}

    for bg in pairs:
        if bg not in bigrams:
            bigrams[bg] = 0
        bigrams[bg] += 1
    return bigrams

print(get_bigrams(usr_input))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only knowledge learnt from previous modules of the Grok Learning Python Course mentioned by the OP, this code works fine in performing what was required:

```
counts = {} # this creates a dictionary for the bigrams and the tally for each one
n = 2
a = input('Line: ').lower().split() # the input is converted into lowercase, then split into a list
while a:
  for x in range(n, len(a)+1):
    b = tuple(a[x-2:x]) # the input gets sliced into pairs of two words (bigrams)
    counts[b] = counts.get(b,0) + 1 # adding the bigrams as keys to the dictionary, with their count value set to 1 initially, then increased by 1 thereafter
  a = input('Line: ').lower().split()  
for c in counts:
  if counts[c] > 1: # tests if the bigram occurs more than once
    print(' '.join(c) + ':', counts[c]) # prints the bigram (making sure to convert the key from a tuple into a string), with the count next to it
```

Note: You may need to scroll right to fully view the notes made on code.

It is pretty straightforward and doesn't require importing anything, etc. I realise I am quite late to the conversation, but hopefully anyone else doing the same course / struggling with similar problems will find this answer helpful.